# I don't understand the Scope

Tags: javascript

1 - why when I run the below code I got **undefind** instead **"a=1"** ?

```
function f1(){a=1; f2();}
function f2(){return a;}
var a= 5;
a = f1();
​alert(a);​
```

like this example the resualt is **"a=1"**.

```
function f1(){a=1; f2();}
function f2(){alert(a);}
var a= 5;
f1();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With

```
a = f1();
```

you are assigning the result of calling `f1` to `a`. Yet, `f1` does not return anything, it evaluates to `undefined`. You'd need to use a `return` statement:

```
function f1(){a=1; return f2(); }
```

Btw, this is not a scope problem. You don't have any variables that are local to your functions, everything accesses the same `a`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably forget a return statement to get your a value

```
function f1(){a=1; return f2();}
function f2(){return a;}
var a= 5;
a = f1();
​alert(a);​
```

Answer (score 1):

`f1` does not return anything that's why
try the below

```
function f1(){a=1; return f2();}
function f2(){return a;}
var a= 5;
a = f1();
​alert(a);​
```

even if does not make lots of sense

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly return from `f1`.

Answer (score 0):

function f1 in 1st example did't returns any value, so that is the reason

Answer (score 0):

During the line a = f1(); the f1 function isn't returning anything so a is getting set to undefined.

I'm not positive what you are trying to do; if you add more I could make a suggestion for how to make it do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`f1()` doesn't return any value. Returning nothing is the same as returning undefined.